# Detect Keyboard event in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

How to detect keyboard events on TextFormField in Flutter? If the user deletes the last letter and presses the delete button again, the cursor should jump back to the previous TextFormField.

I would like to implement a pin-enter screen, something like that one.

https://mobile-solutions.ingenico.com/wp-content/uploads/IMG_022.png

Comment: You can listen to raw key events using https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes you can do that using `onChange` And `FocusScope` for set focus

Here when you delete last letter of second `FormField` focus set on first `FormField`

```
 var firstField = FocusNode();
  var secondField = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        focusNode: firstField,
        onChanged: (text) {
          print("First  field: $text");
        },
      ),
      TextFormField(
        focusNode: secondField,
        onChanged: (text) {
          if (text.length <= 0) {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(firstField);
          }
          print("Second  field: $text");
        },
      )
    ]);
```

}

Comment: How does this work?! onChange doesn't get called on backspace press.

Answer (score 0):

To implement pin-enter screen, You don't have to manage the Keyboard events. As that screen has different button and each button does the entry as its text.

So logically you just have to add the value of the button to the list and remove the value from the list when delete key is pressed.

You can fill the TextField with the length and data of the list.

Comment: Yes that would work but I would like to use the keyBoard from the device ;D

Comment: In that case, can you please share exact screen what exactly you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps you. I faced a similar situation and this is how I did it!

```
        class _OtpEntryFormState extends StatelessWidget {

        final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

        //Declare your focusNodes
        FocusNode node1 = FocusNode();
        FocusNode node2 = FocusNode();
        FocusNode node3 = FocusNode();
        FocusNode node4 = FocusNode();

        String pin1;
        String pin2;
        String pin3;
        String pin4;


        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Now create a row widget, where we'll be adding our textboxes
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[

                  //TextBox1
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                      ],
                      focusNode: node1,
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        if (text.length == 1) {
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node2);
                          pin1 = text;
                        } 
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    )
                  ),

                  //Spacing in-between textbox
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20
                  ),

                  //TextBox2
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                      ],
                      focusNode: node2,
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        if (text.length == 1) {
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node3);
                          pin2 = text;
                        } 
                        else if (text.isEmpty) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node1);
                          }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    )
                  ),

                  //Spacing in-between textbox
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20
                  ),

                  //TextBox3
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                      ],
                      focusNode: node3,
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        if (text.length == 1) {
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node4);
                          pin3 = text;
                        } 
                        else if (text.isEmpty) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node2);
                          }
                      },
                    )
                  ),

                  //Spacing in-between textbox
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20
                  ),

                  //TextBox4
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                      ],
                      focusNode: node4,
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        if (text.length == 1) {
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node4);
                          pin4 = text;
                        } 
                        else if (text.isEmpty) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node3);
                          }
                      },
                    )
                  ), 
                ],
              ),

              //Spacing Between the textbox row and the submit button
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              //Submit Button
              SizedBox(
                width: 30,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      String fullPin = pin1+pin2+pin3+pin4;

                      String combinedPin = fullPin; 

                      int intPin = int.parse(combinedPin);
                      print("OPT Pin: " + intPin.toString());
                    }
                  },
                  child: 
                    Text(
                      'SUBMIT',
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is kinda old but I was facing a similar issue and found no answer anywhere, but I eventually figured something out so here is my answer, I did something like this:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: List.generate(
              6,
              (index) => SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                child: KeyboardListener(
                    focusNode: FocusNode(),
                    onKeyEvent: (value) {
                      if (value.logicalKey.keyLabel == "Backspace") {
                        if (index > 0 && controllers[index].text.isEmpty) {
                          FocusScope.of(context)
                              .requestFocus(focusNodes[index - 1]);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: TextField(
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      controller: controllers[index],
                      focusNode: focusNodes[index],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.gray,
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        if (controllers[index].text.isNotEmpty) {
                          controllers[index].text = value[value.length - 1];
                        }
                        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                          if (index < 5) {
                            FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(focusNodes[index + 1]);
                          }
                        } else {
                          if (index > 0) {
                            FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(focusNodes[index - 1]);
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

controllers is a list of TextEditingControllers and focusNodes is a list of FocusNodes.

Basically, wrap your TextField in a KeyboardListener, that way you can listen for backspace events. Handle the case where the input is not empty with the onChanged from the TextField and the case where the input is empty with the KeyboardListener. Hope this helps anyone who has this question still today!